# php , is it variable or constant

Tags: php

i want  to add  li element to this page,
this website was done by someone else
the index.php file include several php files, along with them main.php.

this is the code for main.php

```
<div class="center"><p class="text3"><?php echo LABEL_TXT_FORNT_PAGE_TITLE;?></p>
<div class="netw"><div>
<div class="title"><?php echo LABEL_TXT_KDMATY;?></div></div>
<p><img src="img/<?php echo $dir;?>/1.jpg" border='1' alt="img" /></p>
<p class="text1"><?php echo TXT_CONTANT_FOR_KDAMATY;?> </p>
<p class="text2"></p>
</div>
<div class="suppserv"><div>  
<div class="title"><?php echo LABEL_TXT_CHECK_PRINTING;?></div></div>
<p><img src="img/<?php echo $dir;?>/2.jpg" border='1' alt="img" /></p>
<p class="text1"><?php echo TXT_CONTANT_FOR_PRINT;?>
</p>
<p class="text2"></p></div>
<div class="remote"><div>
<div class="title"><?php echo LABEL_TXT_POINT_OF_SALES;?></div></div>
<p><img src="img/<?php echo $dir;?>/3.jpg" border='1' alt="img" /></p>
<p class="text1"><?php echo TXT_CONTANT_FOR_SALES;?></p>
<p class="text2"></p></div>
</div>
<div class="line"><img src="img/12.png" alt="img" /></div>
<div class="center2">

<div class="netw">
<p class="text4"><?php echo LABEL_TXT_EXPER;?></p>
<p class="text5"><?php echo TXT_CONTANT_EXPER;?></p>
<ul>
<li><?php echo UL_EXPER_EX1;?></li>
<li><?php echo UL_EXPER_EX2;?></li>
<li><?php echo UL_EXPER_EX3;?></li>
<li><?php echo UL_EXPER_EX4;?></li>
<li><?php echo UL_EXPER_EX5;?></li>
</ul>
<p class="text2"><a href="<?php echo SITE_URL; ?>/expertise.php"><?php echo
LABEL_TXT_MORE_LINKS;?><img alt="img" src="img/<?php echo $dir;?>/11.png"></a></p>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="remote">
<p class="text4"><?php echo LABEL_TXT_CUSTOMER;?></p>
<p class="text5"><?php echo TXT_CONTANT_CUSTOMER;?></p>
<ul>
<li><?php echo UL_CUSTOMER_EX1;?></li>
<li><?php echo UL_CUSTOMER_EX2;?></li>
<li><?php echo UL_CUSTOMER_EX3;?></li>
<li><?php echo UL_CUSTOMER_EX4;?></li>
<li><?php echo UL_CUSTOMER_EX5;?></li>
</ul>

</div>
<div class="suppserv">
<p class="text4"><?php echo LABEL_TXT_OUR_SERVICES;?></p>
<p class="text5"><?php echo TXT_CONTANT_SERVICES;?></p><br />
</div>

</div>
```

note this line :

```
<li><?php echo UL_CUSTOMER_EX1;?></li>
```

can someone explain to me what is this, it is not variable and not a constant, so what is it ?

Comment: Of course it is a constant that has been defined somewhere using `define()`. If you cant see it then it must be defined on an included page.

Comment: I was about to say the same thing, it is either a variable or a constant, and must be defined somewhere...

Comment: *"that has been defined somewhere"*... as in somewhere *else*. Maybe inside an included file.

Comment: Shoot the author.... It looks like a constant though. Look for `define('UL_CUSTOMER_EX1', 'blah')` in previous code.

Comment: @BhavinRana, constants do not require a `$` in the name.

Comment: *"this website was done by someone else the index.php file include several php files..."* By the way people, all answers below won't solve the OP's problem, because chances are, the constant is most probably being defined inside an included file. That's my take on it, and I'm sure the OP is not showing us full code.

Comment: **Here's a comment worthy of an answer:** - Search `*.php` containing `define(UL_CUSTOMER_EX1` then hit the ENTER key - Open the file(s) that contains `UL_CUSTOMER_EX1` and look at what's in there. Then [visit PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php) on the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `define` constants in php like this

```
define("MY_VARIABLE", 6)
```

And then access anywhere on the script:

```
echo MY_VARIABLE; // print 6
```

Is the same that `LABEL_TXT_OUR_SERVICES`

Answer (score 1):

This is a constant, note that it hasn't the dollar sign before.

Refer to this http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.define.php

That constant was declared by using

```
define("UL_CUSTOMER_EX1", 'some_value_or_var');
```

Comment: This answer doesn't solve the OP's problem. This could have been a simple comment if it won't solve the issue at hand.

Comment: @Fred-ii- it *does* solve the issue at hand, the question is "variable or constant". Answer: constant.

Comment: [See my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18765737/php-is-it-variable-or-constant#comment27664094_18765737) It's obvious the OP doesn't know how to deal with this, nor control it. So why hop into a Dragster if you don't know how to drive a Go-Kart? ;-)

Comment: StackOverflow is meant to answer questions, not solve problems for people.  Jose's post is an answer to the one question above: "what is it?"

Comment: @Fred-ii-, it is a bad question, but you cannot blame jose for that. He gave the correct answer.

Comment: @trpt4him A "what is it" question is often best suited as a comment. There is no specific "problem" here.

Comment: @Mischa I'm not "blaming" anyone. Questions such as these literally "open up a can of worms".

Answer (score 1):

Variables' first character is `$` sign in PHP.

```
$var1 = 0; //this is a variable

define('CONST', 100); // is a constant
```

You can use `$var1` and `CONST` in the page with one difference: `$var1`'s value may be changed programatically but constansts no. Value of `CONST` cannot change during the execution of the script

Answer (score 1):

That there is a constant. It must have been `define()`'d somewhere previously, possibly in an included file.

If I were you, I'd search for any `define()` statements that contain `UL_CUSTOMER_EX1`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, i agree with everybody else's opinion: it's a constant defined inside one of the included files.

BUT!

There might be another possibility, which may be probable if the original author is a novice developer:

an UNDEFINED constant, being treated as a string by default from php without warnings enabled.

Because, in PHP, if you use a constant which is undefined, it is reverted to a string which contains the constant name (eg: UNK_CONST becomes the string "UNK_CONST"). Of course it gives a warning too, but warnings may have been suppressed.

Comment: Note that these constants are echoed all over the page. If this was the case, the page would render incorrectly and the OP would have noted that. I consider this possibility implausible.

Comment: @MaximKumpan Yes, i do consider implausible too, but it may help other readers which find constants in legacy code that doesn't appear in their PHP files. It was just worth to mention it.

Comment: Fair point. Good to add.